# R: Using a string as an argument to mutate verb in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, nse, tidyeval

I am building a shiny app which needs to allow users to define new variables for plotting. Specifically I want to allow users to define an expression to be used in mutate verb. The server receives the expression as text and I am wondering how to make mutate execute it in dplyr 0.7. I can make it work (partially) using mutate_ but it is deprecated now. It also defines the new column name as the entire expression rather than the new variable

Here is a reproducible example:

```
input_from_shiny <- "Petal.ratio = Petal.Length/Petal.Width"
iris_mutated <- iris %>% mutate_(input_from_shiny)
```

This gives the following

```
> head(iris_mutated)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Petal.ratio = Petal.Length/Petal.Width
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa                                   7.00
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa                                   7.00
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa                                   6.50
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa                                   7.50
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa                                   7.00
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa                                   4.25
```

Technically,  I can use regular expression to extract new variable name from the string and rename the new column accordingly, but I am wondering what is the correct way to implement it using latest dplyr version (was reading https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html, but could not figure it out)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We can use `rlang::parse_quosure()` together with `!!` (bang bang) to produce the same result:

- `parse_quosure`: parses the supplied string and converts it into a quosure
- `!!`: unquotes a quosure so it can be evaluated by `tidyeval` verbs

Note that `parse_quosure()` was soft-deprecated and renamed to `parse_quo()` in `rlang 0.2.0` per its documentation. If we use `parse_quo()`, we need to specify the environment for the quosures e.g. `parse_quo(input_from_shiny, env = caller_env())`

```r
library(rlang)
library(tidyverse)

input_from_shiny <- "Petal.ratio = Petal.Length/Petal.Width"
iris_mutated <- iris %>% mutate_(input_from_shiny)

iris_mutated2 <- iris %>% 
  mutate(!!parse_quosure(input_from_shiny))
head(iris_mutated2)

#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
#>   Petal.ratio = Petal.Length/Petal.Width
#> 1                                   7.00
#> 2                                   7.00
#> 3                                   6.50
#> 4                                   7.50
#> 5                                   7.00
#> 6                                   4.25


identical(iris_mutated, iris_mutated2)
#> [1] TRUE
```

**Edit:** to separate LHS & RHS

```r
lhs <- "Petal.ratio"
rhs <- "Petal.Length/Petal.Width"

iris_mutated3 <- iris %>% 
  mutate(!!lhs := !!parse_quosure(rhs))
head(iris_mutated3)

> head(iris_mutated3)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
  Petal.ratio
1        7.00
2        7.00
3        6.50
4        7.50
5        7.00
6        4.25
```

Created on 2018-03-24 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: is there a way to automatically make the column name right or the only way is to rename it afterwards?

Comment: You'd have to have the column name as a separate variable or parse it out as a separate variable and use `mutate(!!new_col := !!parse_quosure(rest_of_expression)`

Comment: @Jake: !! is not syntactic sugar because UQ is not a function (and will go away in a future version of rlang)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and heads up! Deleted my previous inaccurate comment.

Answer (score 4):

Package [`friendlyeval`](https://github.com/MilesMcBain/friendlyeval) is a simplified interface to tidy eval that tries to make things a bit more straight forward in cases like these.

Splitting your string in two, you obtain part of the string you wish to use as a column name and part of a string you wish to use as an expression. So you could write:

```
library(friendlyeval)
library(dplyr)
lhs <- "Petal.ratio"
rhs <- "Petal.Length/Petal.Width"

iris_mutated3 <- 
  iris %>% 
  mutate(!!treat_string_as_col(lhs) := !!treat_string_as_expr(rhs))
head(iris_mutated3)
```

By using the function on the lhs, you gain checking that `lhs` can be parsed as plain column name.

`friendlyeval` code can be converted to plain tidy eval code at any time using an RStudio addin.